# addPortalMessage requires decode('utf-8')

Tags: encoding, utf-8, plone

Currently it seems that in order for UTF-8 characters to display in a portal message you need to decode them first.

Here is a snippet from my code:

```
self.context.plone_utils.addPortalMessage(_(u'This document (%s) has already been uploaded.' % (doc_obj.Title().decode('utf-8'))))
```

If Titles in Plone are already UTF-8 encoded, the string is a unicode string and the underscore function is handled by i18ndude, I do not see a reason why we specifically need to decode utf-8.  Usually I forget to add it and remember once I get a UnicodeError.

Any thoughts?  Is this the expected behavior of addPortalMessage?  Is it i18ndude that is causing the issue?

Comment: I'm afraid it is your understanding if how *Python* handles mixing byte strings and Unicode that is the issue here, not anything in Plone.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

UTF-8 is a representation of Unicode, not Unicode and not a Python unicode string. In Python, we convert back and forth between Python's unicode strings and representations of unicode via encode/decode.

Decoding a UTF-8 string via utf8string.decode('utf-8') produces a Python unicode string that may be concatenated with other unicode strings.

Python will automatically convert a string to unicode if it needs to by using the ASCII decoder. That will fail if there are non-ASCII characters in the string -- because, for example, it is encoded in UTF-8.

Comment: Yes, this makes a lot of sense!  I'll keep that it in mind since I deal with a lot of UTF-8 strings.